# vba code to copy multiple pdf files into Clipboard

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 10. I am creating reports of pdf files by VBA code . k= path

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "qrySdMain", acFormatPDF, k, False
```

I want to copy these files into Clipboard through vba code only . Is it possible to copy multiple pdf files into clipboard through VBA ? If yes please help me.

I was able to achieve to copy String into clipboard with this code

```
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Dim strSample As String
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
strSample = "Hello"
clipboard.SetText strSample
clipboard.PutInClipboard
```

but I want to copy pdf files into Clipboard. How can I achieve that ? Thanks for the Help!!!

Comment: Are you trying to import or export pdf via clipboard? Do you mean Windows clipboard?

Comment: @QHarr I am Exporting files into folder. I want that files to be copied into windows clipboard so that whenever I do paste after that process it copies the files that were there in Clipboard

Comment: You are generating reports from Access as pdfs and want all of them to be stored in Windows clipboard so can paste in one go later?

Comment: @QHarr Yes exactly what I want.